# Why my model training decreases while validation is not decreasing, training accuracy increases and validation accuracy is not Increase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I`m using about 4600 training Xray images split on a 70:30 ration. I thought i have a good training sample sets but the model is misbehaving unexpectedly. Below are the graphs that paint the picture of the model perfomances.

My CCN Looks like below:

`INPUT_SHAPE = (224, 224, 3)`
`inp = tensorflow.keras.layers.Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)`

`conv1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3),  activation='relu', padding='same')(inp)`

`pool1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)`

`norm1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(pool1)`

`drop1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3)(norm1)`

`conv2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),  activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)`

`pool2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)`

`norm2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(pool2)`

`drop2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3)(norm2)`

`flat = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten()(drop2)`  #Flatten the matrix to get it ready for dense.

`hidden1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.03))`

`norm4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden1)`

`drop4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(norm4)`

`out = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(drop4)`   #units=1 gives error

`model_1 = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)`

`model_1.summary()`

***Please help if l am missing something here. I am classifying Xray images.***

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about it is _behaving unexpectedly_?

Answer (score 2):

Your model is over-fitting. Usually, this happens when your dataset is not well sampled or your model is too much complicated for your Dataset. Sample your dataset properly and train your model not more than 20 epochs. Also, we can normalize your images to x/255.0 and omit BatchNormalization layers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your validation set isn't sampled well. Try shuffling your dataset first then split it in train, validation, and test set.

Comment: I have shuffled. Maybe its it maybe the incorrect method of shuffling:                                                                                                                            
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split   
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical  

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
train_dataset, train_label = shuffle(img_data_list_train,labels , random_state=2 )     
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_dataset, np_utils.to_categorical(train_label), test_size = 0.30, random_state = 23)

Comment: you will get an idea if you manually go through some of the images in each set.

Comment: Also, the Batch normalization layer usually comes after Conv layer, not after pooling. you can try changing that.

Answer (score 0):

A high training accuracy accompanied by a low validation accuracy indicates you are overfitting to your training data. I would recommend using a [Residual Network](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-coding-a-resnet-in-keras-446d7ff84d33) which is standard for a non-trivial image processing deep learning task.

Comment: @Abulah F, I see Residual Network still gives me high validation that keeps on increasing instead of reducing. however  the training loss keeps decreasing and accuracy also is increasing nicely